# Tikz overlay not working as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays

I am using pdflatex to convert following code into a pdf, and I do not get the expected overlay.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=nasm,style=nasm, escapeinside={<>}]
CodeVersion1:   push    ax      <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (a) {};> 
                push    bx

                mov     ax, bx
                add     ax, bx
                ; some more code

                pop     bx
                pop     ax
                ret

MeasureSize CodeVersion1        <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (b) {};> 

CodeVersion2:   push    ax      <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (c) {};> 
                push    bx

                mov     ax, bx
                sub     ax, bx
                ; some more code

                pop     bx
                pop     ax
                ret

MeasureSize CodeVersion2        <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (d) {};> 

SomeLabel:      push    ax, cx  <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (e) {};> 

                mov     ax, bx
                add     ax, bx
                sub     ax, bx
                ; some more code

                pop     ax, cx
                ret

MeasureSize SomeLabel           <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (f) {};> 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    [
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    brace/.style = {
        decorate,
        decoration={
            brace,
            amplitude=5pt,
            mirror
        }
    }
    ]

    \draw[brace] (a) grid (b);
    \draw[brace] (c) grid (d);
    \draw[brace] (e) grid (f);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to draw the braces from one read dot to the next one but the picture
I get is looking like this:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you make a complete example, with the necessary packages and `listings` definitions?

Comment: That said, why `grid`, and not `--`?

Comment: Now it is looking as it should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--` instead of `grid`. I don't know exactly what happens, but the `grid` operation isn't meant for drawing straight lines between points anyway, and if you try just `\draw (a) grid (b);` you'll see that this is displaced as well.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,listings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={<>}]
CodeVersion1:   push    ax      <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (a) {};> 
                push    bx

                mov     ax, bx
                add     ax, bx
                ; some more code

                pop     bx
                pop     ax
                ret

MeasureSize CodeVersion1        <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (b) {};> 

CodeVersion2:   push    ax      <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (c) {};> 
                push    bx

                mov     ax, bx
                sub     ax, bx
                ; some more code

                pop     bx
                pop     ax
                ret

MeasureSize CodeVersion2        <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (d) {};> 

SomeLabel:      push    ax, cx  <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (e) {};> 

                mov     ax, bx
                add     ax, bx
                sub     ax, bx
                ; some more code

                pop     ax, cx
                ret

MeasureSize SomeLabel           <\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node [circle,fill=red!50] (f) {};> 
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    [
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    brace/.style = {
        decorate,
        decoration={
            brace,
            amplitude=5pt,
%            mirror
        }
    }
    ]

    \draw[brace] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[brace] (c) -- (d);
    \draw[brace] (e) -- (f);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```